# A new Reign beta access code?

Tags: dont-starve-together

I've installed *Don't Starve Together* and gone to properties and selected beta but it says enter beta access code but what is it?

I've tried putting in "anewreign" and "a new reign beta" but nothing is working.

Answer (score 2):

There are some fairly detailed steps on the Klei forums [here](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/69487-how-to-opt-in-to-a-new-reign-beta-for-dont-starve-together/).  **It looks like you should leave the access code blank.**

> - In steam click on Library > Games.
> - Scroll down to Don't Starve Together.
> - Right-click, select Properties.
> - Go to the BETAS tab.
> - In the dropdown, select the "anewreignbeta" branch.
> - In that same properties window, go to the Local Files tab and press Verify Integrity Of Game Cache.
> - Your game will be updated to the beta version.
> - Run the game and go to Browse Games. You should see servers which are running the beta. Have fun!
>     [image][image][image]